# Como recuperar valor de um inteiro e setar em um alertDialog

Tags: android

Ao abrir o alertDialog o resultado fica como zero, segue o código

```
calcular.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String adulto = edit_adulto.getText().toString();
            String crianca = edit_crianca.getText().toString();

            dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Resultado");                
            dialog.setMessage("O valor é: " + resultadoA);
            dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            if (dia.isChecked()){

                if(!adulto.isEmpty()){
                    valorDigitadoA = Integer.parseInt(adulto);
                    resultadoA = valorDigitadoA * 15;
                    dialog.show();
                }
                if(!crianca.isEmpty()){
                    valorDigitadoC = Integer.parseInt(crianca);
                     resultadoC = (valorDigitadoC * 10);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve usar o método `setMessage` dentro da condição logo após atribuir o valor desejado a sua variável. Veja como deve ficar:

```
if(!adulto.isEmpty()){
    valorDigitadoA = Integer.parseInt(adulto);
    resultadoA = valorDigitadoA * 15;

    // aqui será mostrado a mensagem no dialogo 
    // com o valor atribuído a variável resultadoA
    dialog.setMessage("O valor é: " + resultadoA);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: deu certinho amigo, obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Não aparece nada porque você está setando o texto do Dialog com a variável `ResultadoA` antes dela ter algum valor.